# Javascript - merge arrays into json

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I need to merge several arrays into one json and add a value but I'm stuck.
I have this:

```
    var areas = [];
    areas[0] = [];
    areas[1] = ["DE"];
    areas[2] = ["PL","BE","FR",];
    areas[3] = ["US"];
```

and I need this:

```
values: {
  'DE': '#e6f2cc',
  'US': '#e6f2cc',
},
```

So I need to merge the arrays and add "#e6f2cc" as a value to the key.
Is there a fast way to do that? I'm not a JS pro. I managed to merge it but I failed to add the value to this.
Thanks!

Comment: [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)

Comment: And by what logic do only two of those get such a color code assigned, but the value under areas[2] doesn’t?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Something like

```js
var areas = [];
areas[0] = [];
areas[1] = ["DE"];
areas[2] = ["PL", "BE", "FR", ];
areas[3] = ["US"];

var merged = areas.reduce(function(obj, arr) {
  arr.forEach(function(value) {
    obj[value] = '#e6f2cc';
  });
  return obj;
}, {});

console.log(merged);
```

for instance.

The output (the value of `merged`) is

```
{ DE: '#e6f2cc',
  PL: '#e6f2cc',
  BE: '#e6f2cc',
  FR: '#e6f2cc',
  US: '#e6f2cc' }
```